# how can i know what are the shown parts of the html through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to get all the `href` elements of the page that are really shown to the user in the current time (only what inside the browser frame, not the parts that above or under).

For example, if the user is scrolling down in the page, I want to get in my javascript other elements.

Can I even do it? And if not, can I do from Chrome extension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: I search for an answer for Chrome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var res = [];
$("a").each(function(i, el) {
  if (el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
    res.push($(el).eq(i));
    $(el).css({"color":"red", "border":"1px solid red"})
  };
});
console.log($("a").size(), res.length, res);
```