# generic way to check if tag is shown in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, href

I want to filter only the `a`'s that are really shown currently in the browser.

I used `getBoundingClientRect` function, but there are still some cases that I can't filter - like hidden or covered `a` tags.

Is there a more generic way in pure `javascript` to know exactly what are the `a` tags that are really shown currently and the user really can see?

I need it for my chrome extension that uses these tags. So if there is a way to do it using chrome extension API it is a good solution too.

But Mostly the problem is `li` tags where not all the elements inside the list are shown. How can I know what elements are shown and what not?

Thanks!

Comment: `href` is an attribute. Do you mean: "I want to filter only the `a` elements that are really shown currently in the browser"?

Comment: have to loop over the collection and check style values for `display` and `visibility`. If you want only elements visible in viewport will need to determine offsets also and compare to window dimensions and scrolltop

Comment: Do you want to find them once, or continuously get notified whenever they are "visible" / "hidden"? And what do you actually mean by "shown"? Does that mean that the user can visually observe the element, or something else?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25555960/2801559